# Why are cases required in proofs? i.e. in the inequality $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}| \leq \sqrt{|x-y|}$?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

So there is a proof of the inequality needed:

$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}| \leq \sqrt{|x-y|} $ , *where $x$,$y$ $\geq$ $0$*

After squaring both sides:

$(|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|)^2 \leq (\sqrt{|x-y|})^2$

$x + y - 2\sqrt{xy} \leq |x-y|$,

Apparently, now you need cases of:

Case 1: $x \geq y$

Case 2: $x > y$

Case 3: $y > x$

I am asking why you need cases (in general for a proof and specifically this one) and also how would case 3 work? Thanks.

Comment: If you can find a proof that works _without_ dividing into cases, that's fine too.

Comment: Case (2) is redundant.

Comment: Why is case 2 redundant? What about case 4: $x =  y$?

Comment: Why not add case 5: $x=3 \land y=\frac52$, then? Because it's already covered by case (1).

Comment: Okay, so why are you allowed to have greater than and equal to in the same case? Are you not supposed to split them seperaltly into two cases? Why can you not have $x \leq y$ but only $x < y$? Thanks.

Comment: Also why do you consider any cases? Like why do you need cases? Even if it is solvable without them why would you need cases here?

Comment: The expression is symmetrical with $x$ and $y$, so it suffices to prove it for $x\geq y$. Not sure why so many people like to do so many different cases for no reason at all, you just write a lot more.

Comment: The need for cases aside, “Squaring both sides” of something you are trying to prove seems like a bad way to start out.

Comment: @SteveKass Why?

Comment: It’s not a general proof technique to start with the thing you want to prove and manipulate it. Suppose you want to prove that $A\le B$. If you “square both sides” and prove that $A^2\le B^2$, you cannot be sure that $A\le B$. For example, $2^2\le (-3)^2$, but $2$ is not less than or equal to $-3$. If you know that $A$ and $B$ are positive (as they are here), proving that $A^2\le B^2$ is sufficient for proving that $A\le B$, but you should point out that that’s sufficient. A proof of something (like $A\le B$) should *conclude* with the something, not begin with the something.

Comment: @SteveKass That is correct, but I am just doing some rough work before the proof to see if its true. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can consider two main cases, indeed we need $x,y \geq 0$ and

- for $x\ge y \implies \sqrt x \ge \sqrt y$

$$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}| \leq \sqrt{|x-y|} \iff \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y} \leq \sqrt{x-y}$$

- for $x< y \implies \sqrt x < \sqrt y$

$$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}| \leq \sqrt{|x-y|} \iff -\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} \leq \sqrt{-x+y}$$

and since in both cases LHS and RHS are positive we can proceed by squaring both sides.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Why are only two cases considered? What about case 4: $x = y$? Why can you do case 1: with both equal and more than and why aren't they split into two different cases?

Comment: Also, how did you do the second case in your answer? How did you get $-\sqrt{x}$ on the left and $-x$ on the right?

Comment: The key point is that we need $x,y\ge 0$ therefore we have two cases $ x\ge y$ and $x<y$ moreover since $f(t)=\sqrt t$ is strictly increasing when $ x\ge y \iff \sqrt x \ge \sqrt y$ and  $ x< y \iff \sqrt x < \sqrt y$.

Comment: Hi, can you solve the cases in your question to clarify more of my understanding. Also I am not sure what you mean by $f(t) = \sqrt{t}$ is strictly increasing?

Comment: You can solve each one by squaring both sides but first you should understand better what it is going on. Can you see that we have two main cases, that is $x\ge y\ge 0$ and $0\le x<y$. By $f(t)=\sqrt t$ strictky increasing means that $t_1ge t_2\ge 0 \iff \sqrt {t_1} \ge \sqrt {t_2}$. Try to follow every single step ofor the suggestion given and let me know what is not clear step by step.

Comment: Sorry for asking a lot, (but now I get the strictly increasing part, thanks) but some questions are: First, why are the cases mentioned only considered? What about other cases? Also I see that for your cases you squared both sides, but why on the right side is there still a square root? Should it be an absolute value of $|x-y|$ and not $\sqrt{x-y}$? Thanks.

Comment: @Strikers For Q1: given x and y, how many cases there are others than $x\ge y$ or $x<y$?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thanks. What about the second thing mentioned? About the absolute value being removed but not the square root? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, the second step to understand is that $$x\ge y \iff \sqrt x \ge \sqrt y$$.

Comment: Okay, I get your step now, and then the whole proof. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ is defined by a case distinction:
$$
\lvert x \rvert =
\begin{cases}
x & \text{if } x \ge 0 \\
-x & \text{if } x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
So it can be necessary to follow its cases.

Comment: By distinction do you mean it requires cases? Why?

Comment: Okay, your edit makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: Why do we consider $x \geq 0$, like where did the zero come from?

Answer (score 0):

We can assume without loss of generality that $0\leq y\leq x$. 
 $$\sqrt{x-y}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-\frac{y}{x}}\geq\sqrt{x}\left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right)
=\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}\geq\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y},
$$
where I used the result $u\leq\sqrt{u}$ if $0\leq u\leq 1$.

Comment: This is too confusing for me. Sorry. If you know how to, can you explain it from my second step in the post? Thanks.

Comment: if $y\geq x$, just replace $x$ by $y$ and vice-versa above.

Comment: Why should I do that? What is the mathematical reason to do so?

Comment: That covers all possible cases. The $x=y$ is the trivial case, it gives the equality. The $x\geq y$ and the case $y\geq x$ have the same complexity in the proof. I think you don't need to take the square of the inequality as you did.

Comment: I was thinking only about the specific inequality you posted. But I think the idea is basically the same in other similar inequalities.